# Why do hosts disable PHP's fpassthru()?

Tags: php, security

I've been working on a PHP application that uses the [`fpassthru`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) built-in function, which reads contents from a stream or file pointer, and outputs them to the output buffer. It's very similar to the `readfile` function, but allows me to start the output at a specific offset.

Most hosting providers I tested my product with, worked just fine, and these include shared multi-tenant hosting environments. However, I found a few that have the `fpassthru()` function "disabled for security reasons". I spent hours researching why somebody would disable the `fpassthru` function, but not functions such as `fopen`, `fread`, `file_get_contents`, as well as `readfile`, but I couldn't really find anything useful.

This probably sounds silly, but my closest guess is that these hosts disabled `fpassthru` mistaking it for `passthru`, which does indeed warrant disabling, especially in shared environments. Having said that, the actual `passthru` function (along with `exec` and the rest of the family) were also disabled on these hosts.

I tried reaching out to these hosts and asked them why.

I couldn't get past sales at Flywheel, they said they couldn't answer my question, and only support can. And in order to contact support I have to become a customer. Classic.

RunCloud seemed a bit more promising at first, I got through to a "Level 3 Systems Engineer", and it took a few more days to get to a "Sr. Systems Enginneer" from whom I got the following statement:

> it is the best practice for PHP on RunCloud and it is the best practice for us

I asked them to elaborate, but haven't heard back in a while, so I lost hope.

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for ways around `fpassthru()`. I'm looking for reasons why it's occasionally listed alongside "dangerous" functions like `exec()`, `system()`, `passthru()`,  `pcntl_fork()` and others, while having `readfile()`, `file_get_contents()`, etc. work just fine.

If you have any insights, please share!

Comment: you probably want to ask this on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What happens if you ask for an offset outside the file range? Does it read arbitrary memory?

Comment: @shearn89 you can't explicitly specify the offset in fpassthru(). It reads from where the current pointer is to the EOF. To actually offset you'll have to use fread() of fseek().

Answer (score 1):

Do not underestimate the power of cargo cult programmers and systems administrators.

Providers may have had specific issues in the past that required disabling a particular function and simply continue to do so today, simply because their company “has always done so”. And nobody that’s working  there now knows the actual historical event that was the reason behind that.
Let alone if that reasoning still holds true today.